# Is it necessary to make ThreadPoolExecutor as Volatile field？

Tags: volatile, threadpoolexecutor

I want to create a unique thread pool within the app. Is the following "volatile" mandatory?

`private volatile ThreadPoolExecutor cronTaskExecutor`

I am not sure about the ThreadPoolExecutor needs the "volatile"

Some function such as shutdown() will be called by service in different threads.
How to ensure its visibility？